# How to split a string in C#

Tags: c#, string, split

I'm having a string like

```
"List_1 fooo asdf List_2 bar fdsa XList_3 fooo bar"
```

and a `List<String>` like

```
 List<String> l_lstValues = new List<string> { "List_1", "XList_3", "List_2" };
```

I need to split the string based on the value in the `l_lstValues`.

So the splitted substrings will be like

```
List_1 fooo asdf 
List_2 bar fdsa 
XList_3 fooo bar
```

Please post me a way to do this 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, please check my answer.. you can do it in 3 lines. cheers!

Answer (score 3):

You have to use this split method on msdn, you have to pass your List into an array and then, you have to pass as a parameter of the split that array.

I leave you the link here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf(v=VS.90).aspx

If you want to mantain the words you're splitting with, you will have to iterate the resulted array and then add the words in your list, if you have the same order in the string and in the list.

If the order is unknown, you mus use indexOf to locate the words in the list and split the string manually.

See you

Comment: Yes, as you can see on the msdn article, as in a normal split with char[] you lose the words you're splitting with.

Comment: Can't believe this answer got 4 upvotes! @Amedio, can you correct / remove your answer? The OP wants the words that he is splitting on to remain. Don't repeat the same thing I said!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand the question very well, and I thought you were asking to me, so in my opinion, I didn't repeat the same thing you said, sorry another time. I will edit this, now.

Comment: @manojlds in this question I would not trust any votes at all. I got downvoted without reason, this answer was immediately upvoted... hopefully the fraud detection of SO will fix it.

Comment: I'm here to learn and help others with their problem, if I can, so I do not need something to win reputation, I don't even care who upvotes me, only the reason why people downvote me to learn from my mistakes, so please, leave the fraud hypothesis away, and just help each other.

Comment: @Amedio - removed my downvote after the edit. I downvoted only because the answer was not correct and you were not correcting it.

Comment: I was wrong it was early in the morning and I didn't understand your comment very well thanks for the comment :)

Comment: The answer still is not correct. It does only describe, how potentially get to a solution. But it does not give the solution ;)

Comment: how to separate if we have something like  " int a,b ;"  and i want to retrieve only a and b from this string.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like below:

```
string sampleStr = "List_1 fooo asdf List_2 bar fdsa XList_3 fooo bar";
string[] splitStr = 
   sampleStr.Split(l_lstValues.ToArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

**EDIT**: Modified to print the fragments with list word as well

**Assumption**: There is no '`:`' in `sampleStr`

```
foreach(string listWord in l_lstValues)
{
    sampleStr = sampleStr.Replace(listWord, ':'+listWord);
}
string[] fragments = sampleStr.Split(':');
```

Comment: Again, How will this work, you will lose List_1 etc. in the split

Comment: your code does not compile. It misses the StringSplitOptions parameter. Also: why introducing additional assumptions? easier solutions exist.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the most simple and straight-forward solution:

```
    public static string[] Split(string val, List<string> l_lstValues) {
        var dic = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
        string curKey = string.Empty;
        foreach (string word in val.Split(' ')) {
            if (l_lstValues.Contains(word)) {
                curKey = word;
            }
            if (!dic.ContainsKey(curKey))
                dic[curKey] = new List<string>();
            dic[curKey].Add(word);
        }
        return dic.Values.ToArray();
    }
```

There is nothing special about the algorithm: it iterates all incoming words and tracks a 'current key' which is used to sort corresponding values into the dictionary.

EDIT: I simplyfied the original answer to more match the question. It now returns a string[] array - just like the String.Split() method does. An exception will be thrown, if the sequence of incoming strings does not start with a key out of the l_lstValues list.

Comment: Obviously somebody is afraid of my answer :) But downvoting without any sense does not make the answer worse. The OP should review this one and compare it to the other answers, which are simply plain wrong or much more clumsy.

Comment: You have my upvote! ;) I'll see if I can code my solution just to post it here to have a more complete solution! Thanks for the comment

Answer (score 1):

You can replace every string of the list in the original string with an added control character, and then split on that caracter. For instance, your original string:

```
List_1 fooo asdf List_2 bar fdsa XList_3 fooo bar
```

Need to become:

```
List_1 fooo asdf;List_2 bar fdsa;XList_3 fooo bar
```

Which will later be split based on `;`, producing the desired result. For that, i use this code:

```
string ori = "List_1 fooo asdf List_2 bar fdsa XList_3 fooo bar" 
foreach (string word in l_lstValues) {
    ori = ori.Replace(word, ";" + word);
}
ori = ori.Replace(" ;", ";"); // remove spaces before ;
ori = Regex.Replace(ori, "^;", ""); // remove leading ;
return (ori.split(";"));
```

You could also assemble the following regular expression:

```
(\S)(\s?(List_1|XList_3|List_2))
```

The first token `(\S)` will prevent replacing the first occurrence, and the second token `\s?` will remove the space. Now we use it to add the `;`:

```
string ori = "List_1 fooo asdf List_2 bar fdsa XList_3 fooo bar" 
string regex = "(\S)(\s?(" + String.Join("|", l_lstValues) + "))";
ori = Regex.Replace(ori, regex, "$1;$3");
return (ori.split(";"));
```

The regex option is a bit more dangerous because the words can contain scape sequences.

Comment: in your question comment you said "you can do it in 3 lines". Now which are those 3 lines?

Comment: the last one.. since the first line is just assigning the test string

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
            string a = "List_1 fooo asdf List_2 bar fdsa XList_3 fooo bar";
            List<String> l_lstValues = new List<string> { "List_1", 
                                                      "XList_3", "List_2" };

            var e = l_lstValues.GetEnumerator();
            e.MoveNext();
            while(e.MoveNext())
            {
                var p = a.IndexOf(e.Current);
                a = a.Insert(p, "~");
            }
            var splitStrings = a.Split(new string[]{" ~"},StringSplitOptions.None);
```

So here, I insert a `~` whenever I encounter a element from the list ( except for the first, hence the outside `e.MoveNext()` ) and then split on `~` ( note the preceding space) The biggest assumption is that you don't have `~` in the string, but I think this solution is simple enough if you can find such a character and ensure that character won't occur in the original string. If character doesn't work for you, use something like `~~@@` and since my solution shows string split with `string[]` you can just add the entire string for the split.

Of course you can do something like:

```
foreach (var sep in l_lstValues)
        {
            var p = a.IndexOf(sep);
            a = a.Insert(p, "~");

        }
```

but that will have an empty string, and I just like using `MoveNext()` and `Current` :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [String.IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s.aspx) method to get the index of the starting character for each phrase in your list.

Then, you can use this index to split the string.

```
string input = "A foo bar B abc def C opq rst";
List<string> lstValues = new List<string> { "A", "C", "B" };
List<int> indices = new List<int>();

foreach (string s in lstValues)
{
    // find the index of each item
    int idx = input.IndexOf(s);

    // if found, add this index to list
    if (idx >= 0)
       indices.Add(idx);        
}
```

Once you have all the indices, sort them:

```
indices.Sort();
```

And then, use them to get resulting strings:

```
// obviously, if indices.Length is zero,
// you won't do anything

List<string> results = new List<string>();
if (indices.Count > 0)
{
    // add the length of the string to indices
    // as the "dummy" split position, because we
    // want last split to go till the end
    indices.Add(input.Length + 1);

    // split string between each pair of indices
    for (int i = 0; i < indices.Count-1; i++)
    {
        // get bounding indices
        int idx = indices[i];
        int nextIdx = indices[i+1];

        // split the string
        string partial = input.Substring(idx, nextIdx - idx).Trim();

        // add to results
        results.Add(partial);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code i made. This will get the substring you need provided that your key splitters are sequentially located from left to right of your original string.

```
var oStr ="List_1 fooo asdf List_2 bar fdsa XList_3 fooo bar";
        List<String> l_lstValues = new List<string> { "List_1", "List_2", "XList_3" };

        List<string> splitted = new List<string>();
        for(int i = 0; i < l_lstValues.Count; i++)
        {
            var nextIndex = i + 1 >= l_lstValues.Count  ? l_lstValues.Count - 1 : i + 1;
            var length = (nextIndex == i ? oStr.Length : oStr.IndexOf(l_lstValues[nextIndex])) - oStr.IndexOf(l_lstValues[i]);
            var sub = oStr.Substring(oStr.IndexOf(l_lstValues[i]), length);
            splitted.Add(sub);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code achieving this task

```
        string str = "List_1 fooo asdf List_2 bar fdsa XList_3 fooo bar";
        List<String> l_lstValues = new List<string> { "List_1", "XList_3", "List_2" };

        string[] strarr = str.Split(' ');
        string sKey, sValue;
        bool bFlag = false;
        sKey = sValue = string.Empty;

        var lstResult = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

        foreach (string strTempKeys in l_lstValues)
        {
            bFlag = false;
            sKey = strTempKeys;
            sValue = string.Empty;

            foreach (string strTempValue in strarr)
            {
                if (bFlag)
                {
                    if (strTempValue != sKey && l_lstValues.Contains(strTempValue))
                    {
                        bFlag = false;
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                        sValue += strTempValue;
                }
                else if (strTempValue == sKey)
                    bFlag = true;
            }

            lstResult.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(sKey, sValue));                
        }
```